# C - Printing a 2D Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, char

How do I print the elements of a 2D Char Array in C?

Here is my current code:

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int size;

  printf("Enter size:\n");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  char word[size][size];

  //Enter the matrix
  for(int k = 0; k < (size); ++k){
    for (int j = 0; j < (size); ++j){
      printf("Enter letter:");
      scanf("%c",&word[k][j]);
    }
  }

  //printf("\n");
  for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k){
    for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){

      printf("%c",word[k][j]);
    }
    //printf("\n ");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

When executed it returns the element in pairs (using a 4x4 array)
Example:

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij
kl
mn
op
```

Rather than my desired output:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

Why is this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You're not explicitly printing any newlines until the very end, so the rest of them are probably coming from your input.  Are you entering all of the values on a single line before hitting the enter key?  If not, then `scanf` will store the newlines in `word`.

Comment: use %u format specifier for unsigned int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

changing your scanf solves all the problems

```
scanf(" %c",&word[k][j]);  // notice the space before '%c'
```

And also you need to change your printing loop to this

```
for (k = 0; k < size; ++k){
    for(j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        printf("%c",word[k][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the reading and it seems like printing is ok:

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int size = 4;
    char word[size][size];

    //Enter the matrix
    for (int k = 0; k < (size); ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (size); ++j) {
            word[k][j] = 'a' + j + (k * size);
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {

            printf("%c", word[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware: `%c` and `%1s` do different things (apart from adding a terminating null for the latter):

- `c` take every character **including space, tab, cr and lf**
- `%1s` skip over all blanks (space, tab, cr, lf, etc.)

So at input time, you should use:

```
char c[2]; // provide room for a terminating null...
...
for(int k = 0; k < (size); ++k){
    for (int j = 0; j < (size); ++j){
        printf("Enter letter:");
        scanf("%1s",c);
        word[k][j] = c[0];
    }
}
```

And at print time:

```
for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k){
    for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
        printf("%c",word[k][j]);
    }
    printf("\n "); // new line after each line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two issues with your source.

One is the memory allocation - that is actually not ansi-c.

If you need dynamic memory you need to allocate it at runtime. Consider switching to c++ since there are standard facilities that help with that in a safer way.

The second issue was that there is a whitespace character in the buffer that is used as an input character. I think you want to clear that.

Here is the source with additional comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ansiC()
{
    unsigned int size;

    printf("Enter size:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    //char word[size][size]; <- this is not ansi-c because size is unknown at compile time
    char * word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* size * size);


    //Enter the matrix
    for (int k = 0; k < (size); ++k)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (size); ++j)
        {
            printf("Enter letter:");
            scanf("%c ", &word[k * size + j]);
            //since word is just a pointer i changed the way the position is calculated
            //after the character the user presses the enter key
            //this puts a whitespace character on the buffer. 
            //by adding the space after %c you also clear that from the buffer
        }
    }

    //printf("\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {

            printf("%c", word[k * size + j]);
            //since word is just a pointer i changed the way the position is calculated
        }
        //printf("\n ");
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(word); //if you use malloc you need to remember to use free
}

int main()
{
    ansiC();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this response involving pointers. It actually helped me understand them better! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please check this .

```
# include <iostream.h>
# include <conio.h>


void main()
{
clrscr();
char arr[5][3]={"abc","aks","tny","dkn","kbf"};
    for(int a=0;a<5;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<3;b++)
        {
            cout<<" "<<arr[a][b];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }


 getch();
}
```