# how to print permutations of array of strings in c without recursion?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, permutation

Is anyone here who can explain me how to print the permutations of a array of strings in iterative method without using recursion. Please explain with code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You might have a look at `std::next_permutation`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When I made this comment, the tag C++ was present (removed by Alan Birtles?). Moreover, the link provides an example of implementation. It is in C++, but it may help OP to implement their own code in C

Answer (score 1):

If the string is "abcd", put all of the "a" chars in position 0 for the first n-1! arrays, in position 1 for the next n-1! arrays, etc. Then put all of the "b" chars in position 1 for the first n-2! arrays, etc, all of the "c" chars in position 2 for the first n-3! arrays, etc, and all of the "d" chars in position 3 for the first n-4! arrays, etc, using modulo n arithmetic in each case to move from position 3 to position 0 as you are filling out the arrays.

Comment: Make some research effort and come back then my answer will be clear.

Comment: I am unable to understand your logic, but i think you are describing how to print permutations of "abcd" but my question is how to print permutations of { "abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"} please explain this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936358/c-printing-a-2d-char-array
The question and answers in this link I think will help you.